# Layout of three divs with fixed width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to position three divs. The middle div in the center has fixed width. The other two should split equally the remaining space.

My html:

```
<div class="menu-header" role="banner">
    <div>header left</div>
    <div class="container">header middle</div>
    <div>header right</div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.menu-header{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-header{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Using this code, left and right divs are of different width, which
is making the center div to lean towards left or right.

Answer (score 2):

Both the style blocks are using same class

Try - 
   `.menu-header div{
       display: table-cell;
   }`

Check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/zq7g6pLo/

Comment: On doing that, three divs are positioned side by side. but the center div is not positioned in the center.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way, jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/r94wf7km/4/

in HTML,

```
<div class="menu-header" role="banner">
    <div class="left-div">header left</div>
    <div class="container">header middle</div>
    <div class="right-div">header right</div>
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
.menu-header{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.left-div{
    float:left;
}
.right-div{
    float:right;
}
.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;  /*fixed width*/
    margin-left: -100px; /*half of width*/
}
.left-div,
.right-div{
    width: calc((100% - 200px)/2);   /*give half of available space to both div*/
}
```

Comment: How much of this solution is browser compatible because cal() is not supported in many of the browsers?

Comment: On desktop the concerns would be it's IE 9+, Safari 6+, and won't be in Opera until it is on Blink in 15+. On mobile, Android and Opera Mini don't support it at all yet and iOS on 6.0+.

Answer (score 0):

margin auto can make it to center
1st way:

```
.container{
    margin:auto
}
```

2nd way:

```
.menu-header{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-header{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

but display table makes your randring somewhat slow